# $PATH - No such file or directory (but all files and directories exist)

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts, environment-variables

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and at first when I was attempting to use a script that would do the following:

```
. ~/.bashrc

conda activate {env}
```

I would receive an error that conda init needs to be run. However, I had ran it and then did it again as prompted but nothing was modified. So after some searching, I decided to check my PATH variable and I receive this:

```
10:55:42  |base|local@office-dana-group ~ → $PATH
bash: /home/local/mambaforge/bin:/home/local/mambaforge/condabin:/home/local/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:
/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin: No such file or directory
```

The thing is that all these directories and files exist so I cannot determine why I am receiving the 'No such file or directory message'

Comment: Use `echo "$PATH"` to show the contents of the variable. Using the variable alone means bash tries to run the contents as a command - which doesn't exist indeed.

Comment: `$PATH` isn't a commend to be run. It's a variable, and you can use, e.g., `echo "$PATH"` or `declare -p PATH` to show the variable's contents. You're trying to run the entirety of `home/local/mambaforge/bin:/home/local/mambaforge/condabin:/home/local/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:
/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin` as a command, and of course such there's no file

Answer (score 0):

to add a path to your `$PATH` variable, add this to your `.bashrc` file

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/your/command
```

To reload your `.bashrc` file, run `exec bash`

Comment: I have hard time interpreting what does the line starting with `export`. Could you please allow insight into what it means?